# Two concurrent string replaces in kotlin string

Tags: string, replace, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I have a string with wrong directed paranthesis, I want to replace **(** with **)** and **)** with **(** at same time, can I do it with a single **replace** method or I should use a loop?

For example I have this string : **You need extra time ) or money (**

Which should be like this : **You need extra time ( or money )**

Comment: Please take a look at my update, it's very beautiful :D

Comment: great! I liked compressed expressions

Comment: This has little to do with concurrency, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes♂you♂can.

With the help of `Regex`, you can do a lot of things.

i.e. we have a `"()"`:

```
"()".replace(Regex("[()]")) {
    when (it.value) {
        "(" -> ")"
        ")" -> "("
        else -> ""
    }
}
```

And the result is `")("` (I tested it under Kotlin 1.2.10).
This one is very readable.

A one-linear way, more tricky:

```
"()".replace(Regex("[()]")) { ")("["()".indexOf(it.value[0])].toString() }
```

This one is unreadable.

Comment: "is unreadable, but looks better" - wut, this doesn't make sense! :)

Comment: I think a one-linear one is always better than a 7-line one... I'll edit it.